# Unwanted margin-bottom in bootstrap .well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

This is the site [link](http://find.netai.net/). The footer is the bootstrap's `.well`. It has some default `margin-bottom` you can see that with inspect element option. Now I have tried everything that I knew to remove the margin bottom ( Except editing the original bootstrap file I don't think I would need to do that ). For example:

```
footer.well { margin-bottom: 0px !important; }
```

I've also tried doing inline css but no use. Can anyone help me?
Note: If I remove the margin with the inspect element tool, it gives me the exact result I want.

Comment: Awesome really guys thank you very much. All of you but I can accept only one answer

Comment: Checkout my answer here, It might help you.
Here is the link, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075323/12155745)

Comment: Checkout my answer, It might help you.
here is the link, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075323/12155745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do there changes to fix this.

**1) Indeed remove the bottom margin AND the 1px bottom border:**

```
footer.well {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

*No need for `!important` here though*

**2) The element will still be shifted to the top because its parent element forces it to do so. Cancel that rule by removing it. Change:**

```
<div style="position: relative; top: -30px;" class="nav_wrapper padding">
```

to simply

```
<div class="nav_wrapper padding">
```

**3) Once removed at the top there will be a 30x gap because you just recreated it to clear the bottom. Here is a much cleaner way to recreate it without modifying the bottom:**

```
#header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

All CSS rules must be declared **after** the bootstrap CSS file rules. Preferably from another file loaded after.

Answer (score 3):

One of parent divs have relative position and "top: -30px;" defined, if you remove that all comes to order

This is the line:

```
<div style="position: relative; top: -30px;" class="nav_wrapper padding">
```

Just redefine this to top: 0; and there you have it. Rest of padding is footer actual padding which you can remove with:

```
footer.well { margin-bottom: 0px !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `margin-bottom: 0px;` to `footer.footer-home` within `custom.css` should solve your problem.