# How to remove gap after footer in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my html code (live demo http://...) but the footer is not at the very bottom of the page, there is a gap after footer. How should I fix it? and what changes do I need in css/html? I am using bootstrap 4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Cart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/1061ab0407.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar {margin-bottom: 20px;}

.card {
        margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
        float: none; /* Added */
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
}

.table.no-border tr td, .table.no-border tr th {
  border-width: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- header -->

     <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8">
                   <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                           <table class="table">
                                       <thead>
                                                   <tr>
                                                         <th>Product</th>
                                                          <th>Price</th>
                                                          <th>Quantity</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody>
                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                   <td>blah1</td>
                                                   <td>$12.10</td>
                                                   <td>
                                                          <form action="/new/cart/100" method="post" class="form-inline">
                                                              <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="6" class="form-control input-sm">
                                                              <input type="hidden" name="item" value="2">
                                                              <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                                           </form>
                                                   </td>
                                            </tr>

                                                                                                                         </tbody>
                           </table>
                   </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                   <h4 class="card-title">Cart summary</h4>
                   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                 <li class="list-group-item">Total</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item">$17.60</li>

 <li class="list-group-item">Coupon
<form action="/new/cart/100" method="post" class="form-inline">
<input type="text" name="coupon" value="" size="10" class="form-control input-sm">
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
</form></li>

                   </ul>
                                 <a href="/coursecode1/slim/public/order" class="btn btn-default">Checkout</a>
       <!-- /div -->
           </div>
     </div>

<!-- footer -->
</div>
</div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
   <center>All Rights Reserved.</center>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the footer to be at the very bottom of the page, without gap after it, how to do so?

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` right before `<div id="footer">`, the browser parses it as if the footer is a child of `#wrap`, hence the incorrect position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CSS's `calc()` function in `min-height` property. And wrap the `.col-md-8` and `.col-md-4` inside a parent div (`.main-content` in my case). Like,

**In HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <nav>...</nav>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">...</div>
  </div>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

**In CSS:**

```
.main-content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 136px); /* Total viewport height - (height of navbar + height of footer) */
}
```

**Have a look at the snippet below (*use full preview*):**

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {}

.main-content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 136px);
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar { margin-bottom: 20px; }

.card {
        margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
        float: none; /* Added */
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
}

.table.no-border tr td, .table.no-border tr th {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Cart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/1061ab0407.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
  <div class="main-content">

<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- header -->

     <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8">
                   <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                           <table class="table">
                                       <thead>
                                                   <tr>
                                                         <th>Product</th>
                                                          <th>Price</th>
                                                          <th>Quantity</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody>
                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                   <td>blah1</td>
                                                   <td>$12.10</td>
                                                   <td>
                                                          <form action="/new/cart/100" method="post" class="form-inline">
                                                              <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="6" class="form-control input-sm">
                                                              <input type="hidden" name="item" value="2">
                                                              <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                                           </form>
                                                   </td>
                                            </tr>

                                                                                                                         </tbody>
                           </table>
                   </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                   <h4 class="card-title">Cart summary</h4>
                   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                 <li class="list-group-item">Total</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item">$17.60</li>

 <li class="list-group-item">Coupon
<form action="/new/cart/100" method="post" class="form-inline">
<input type="text" name="coupon" value="" size="10" class="form-control input-sm">
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
</form></li>

                   </ul>
                                 <a href="/coursecode1/slim/public/order" class="btn btn-default">Checkout</a>
       <!-- /div -->
           </div>
     </div>

<!-- footer -->
</div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
   <center>All Rights Reserved.</center>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Saurav. Would you please help for this one too?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196897/how-to-have-jquery-to-return-csrf

Answer (score 2):

Add `width:100%` and `position : absolute` and `bottom: 0px`

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

`position:fixed` would work just fine in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Actually the elegant way is using Js or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what that worked for me,

```
<footer>
 <p class="text-center bg-dark text-white p-2 mb-0">Copyright 1990-2020 by Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

In the above code, the thing which is just creating difference is **mb-0**, In **Bootstrap 4**, **mb** stands for margin bottom. By writing **mb-0** we are assigning as margin from bottom is 0dp.